# emgucv, cant find opencv_core220.dll and opencv_imgproc220.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to use emgucv with visual studio. I have followed the instructions on http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp and i cant find the two dll files opencv_core220.dll and opencv_imgproc220.dll that i am supposed to link with visual studio. I have tried downloading opencv to see, if the files were supposed to be there, but no luck, i honestly have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing the same question as i am the tutorial needs to be updated and iunstead of using those two files use the dll-s in the Emgu\emgucv-windesktop 3.1.0.2504\bin\x64 folder.